# Does flash player 10.3 supports p2p streaming?

Tags: flash, streaming, p2p

I'm new to flash, but I just found infos about flash player 10.1 and p2p streaming.

Answer (score 0):

[RTMP](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/) was designed to allow two or more flash clients to communicate P2P. It has been available in the Flash Player since version 10.1. The only downside is that is relies on Adobe's servers so you're tied to their infrastructure and strategic decisions.